# How to iterate $(x-1)/(x\ln{x})=a$ using Newton Raphson

Tags: algebra-precalculus, newton-raphson

I am trying to iterate $\frac{x-1}{x\ln{x}} - a= 0$ to solve for $x$ using Newton Raphson, but it is blowing up. Any ideas why? Is this a strange function to find a root for?

$$x_{i+1} = x_i - f(x_i)/f'(x_i)$$ where $$f'(x) = \frac{-x+\ln(x)+1}{x^2 \ln(x)}$$

Comment: The most common reason for the failure of this method is that a "bad" starting value is selected, i.e. a starting point that is chosen too far away from the root. Have you tried graphing the function first?

Comment: With what value of a and what initial value of x did you iterate?

Comment: One reason it might not be working is because your derivative is wrong - it should have $x^2 \ln^2 x$ in the denominator so you're missing a factor of $\ln x$.